# JSF Primefaces Commandbutton is not updated AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to update the Button "buttonEditRole" after an element of the table
"dataTableSupUserRoles" was selected. The button should get enabled when an element was
selected. The listener method after the row select is called.
In this method i set "disableNewSupUserRoleButton" on true. This also works but the button does not get enabled.
Here is my xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form id="formUserSettingsTabRole">
            <p:panelGrid>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:dataTable id="dataTableSupUserRoles"
                            value="#{userSettingBean.supplierUserRoleList}" var="roles"
                            rowKey="#{roles.ID}"
                            selection="#{userSettingBean.selectedSupUserRole}"
                            selectionMode="single" paginator="true"
                            paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10">

                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                                update=":tabViewUserSettings:formUserSettingsTabRole:buttonEditRole"
                                listener="#{userSettingBean.onSupplierUserRoleRowSelect}" />

                            <p:column headerText="#{msg['global_company_tile']}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{roles.SUPPLIER.NAME}"
                                    styleClass="#{roles.IS_CONFIRMED ? 'textGreen' : 'textRed'}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{msg['global_address_location']}">
                                <h:outputText
                                    value="#{roles.SUPPLIER.CITY}, #{roles.SUPPLIER.COUNTRY}"
                                    styleClass="#{roles.IS_CONFIRMED ? 'textGreen' : 'textRed'}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="#{msg['global_role']}">
                                <h:outputText value="#{roles.ROLE.NAME}"
                                    styleClass="#{roles.IS_CONFIRMED ? 'textGreen' : 'textRed'}" />
                            </p:column>


                            <p:column>
                                <p:commandButton id="ComButSeeCurrentRole" icon="ui-icon-search"
                                styleClass="ui-blockui"/>

                                <p:overlayPanel for="ComButSeeCurrentRole">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="bababubu"/>
                                </p:overlayPanel>
                            </p:column>




                            <p:column headerText="#{msg['global_company_delete']}">
                                <p:commandButton id="ComButtDeleteSupUsRole" title="Delete"
                                    immediate="true" type="submit" update="dataTableSupUserRoles"
                                    actionListener="#{userSettingBean.deleteSupplierUserRole}"
                                    icon="ui-icon-trash">
                                    <f:param name="delteSupUserRole" value="#{roles.ID}" />
                                </p:commandButton>
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandButton id="buttonAddRole" value="#{msg['global_new']}" />

                        <p:overlayPanel id="OverLayPanelNewRole" for="buttonAddRole"
                            styleClass="ui-blockui">

                            <p:dataTable id="DataTableCompany"
                                value="#{userSettingBean.supplierList}" var="company"
                                selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{company.ID}"
                                selection="#{userSettingBean.selectedSupplier}" paginator="true"
                                paginatorPosition="bottom">

                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userSettingBean.onNewSupUserRoleTableSelect}"
                                update=":tabViewUserSettings:formUserSettingsTabRole:CommandButtonSaveNewRole"/>


                                <p:column headerText="#{msg['global_company_tile']}">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{company.NAME}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Location">
                                    <p:outputLabel value="#{company.location}" />
                                </p:column>

                            </p:dataTable>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['global_role']}" />

                            <p:selectOneMenu id="SelectOneMenuRoles"
                                value="#{userSettingBean.selectedRole}" converter="roleIDConverter">

                                <f:selectItems value="#{userSettingBean.roleList}" var="role"
                                    itemLabel="#{role.NAME}" itemValue="#{role}" style="width:100%" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>


                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['global_company_comment']}" />

                            <p:inputTextarea id="inpTxtACompCommentMyRole" rows="6" cols="33"
                                value="#{userSettingBean.newRoleComment}" maxlength="1000"
                                style="width:97%" />

                            <p:commandButton id="CommandButtonSaveNewRole" value="#{msg['global_company_form_status_create']}"
                                actionListener="#{userSettingBean.addSupplierUserRole}"
                                immediate="true" disabled="#{userSettingBean.disableNewSupUserRoleButton}"
                                update="dataTableSupUserRoles formUserSettingsTabRole" />


                        </p:overlayPanel>




                        <p:commandButton id="buttonEditRole" value="#{msg['global_company_form_status_edit']}"
                            disabled="#{userSettingBean.disableNewSupUserRoleButton}"
                            actionListener="#{userSettingBean.editSupplierUserRole}"
                            update="buttonEditRole outPLabelCompNameEdit dataTableSupUserRoles"
                            immediate="true" />


                        <p:outputLabel id="testLabel"
                            value="#{selectedSupUserRole.SUPPLIER.NAME}" />


                        <p:overlayPanel id="OverLayPanelEditRole" for="buttonEditRole"
                            styleClass="ui-blockui">
                            <p:panelGrid columns="2">

                                <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['global_company_tile']}" />

                                <p:outputLabel id="outPLabelCompNameEdit" disabled="true"
                                    value="#{selectedSupUserRole.SUPPLIER.NAME}" />

                                <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['global_role']}" />



                                <p:selectOneMenu id="SelectOneMenuRolesEdit"
                                    value="#{userSettingBean.selectedRole}" onchange="submit()"
                                    valueChangeListener="#{userSettingBean.roleChanged}">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{userSettingBean.roleList}" var="role"
                                        itemLabel="#{role.NAME}" style="width:100%" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>

                            </p:panelGrid>

                            <p:outputLabel value="#{msg['global_company_comment']}" />
                            <p:inputTextarea id="inpTxtACompCommentMyRoleEdit" rows="6"
                                cols="33" value="#{userSettingBean.newRoleComment}"
                                maxlength="1000" style="width:97%" />

                            <p:commandButton value="#{msg['global_company_save']}"
                                actionListener="#{userSettingBean.saveEditedSupUserRole}"
                                immediate="true"
                                update="dataTableSupUserRoles formUserSettingsTabRole" />
                        </p:overlayPanel>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>


            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>

    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And the listener method:

```
public void onSupplierUserRoleRowSelect(SelectEvent e){

    this.disableSupUserRoleButtons=false;
}
```

Comment: Just for test try remove the tag immediate or change the value to false, if not work try change your update code in ajav event to @form

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
i tried your two tips, but it still does not work.

Comment: @hiaslosch17 what's the scope of the backing bean? `@ViewScoped` is always recommended for best results with ajax operations

Answer (score 0):

you can update entire form instead of command button.

try this:

```
update = "@form"
```